# Can't import csnd6 for Csound's python API

Tags: python, api, import, csound

I try to use Csound's Python API.
Therefore, I try to import the 'csnd6' package:
`import csnd6`.

For some reason, the package is not installed on my machine:
`ImportError: No module named csnd6`.

This is my setup:
- Python 2.7.11
- Csound 6.08
- Mac OS X 10.12.1

How can I fix it?
(or) How can I install this package?

Thanks!!

Comment: It seems you installed icsound for a version of python that doesn't have sound,,probably the default `python 2.6`,,how did you install `python 2.7`?and what is the outcome of `which python` on terminal?

Comment: I installed python from python.org.  The outcome of ``which python`` is ``/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python``.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

From the [Csound 6.08 release notes](https://github.com/csound/csound/releases/tag/6.08.0):

> *"ctcsound.py, a new FFI interface for Python was introduced in version 6.07.
>
>   It is now the recommended interface for Python,
>
>   **csnd6.py being deprecated**."*

Here is the link to the `ctcsound.py` package repository -
https://github.com/fggp/ctcsound

NOTE: You might have to add the `ctcsound.py` file to the Python packages folder manually: 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`